# Why does SQL Return too Many Results?

Tags: mysql, join

When I enter this query,

```
SELECT OrderDetails.OrderDetailID, Customers.CustomerName
  FROM OrderDetails, Customers 
       NATURAL JOIN Products
       NATURAL JOIN Customers
WHERE SupplierID = 5;
```

1001 records are returned.

When I enter this query,

```
SELECT OrderDetailID
  FROM OrderDetails 
       NATURAL JOIN Products
WHERE SupplierID = 5;
```

11 records are returned

As you might expect there are 91 records in the Customer table and 11 results are returned in the second query and 91*11=1001. I don't know how to get rid of this however and to prevent duplicate results being returned in the first query such as this.

[Duplicate Returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbSNC.png)

Schema's attached: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

Comment: I'd stay away from natural joins, they save you a little amount of typing for no real benefit and a lot of unpredictability in the long run (for example, later, after the project has grown, "standardized" timestamps are added to tables; now your previously working NATURAL JOIN only returns results with identical timestamps).

Comment: ^^ Yes, please post the table structures so we can provide an accurate answer without guessing. But the problem is due to using `FROM OrderDetails, Customers` wherein you've created a cartesian product with an implicit inner join due to the comma syntax.

Comment: The link you included does not actually show the schema. Please edit the question to add the `CREATE TABLE` statements directly here.

Comment: I didn't make the table. I am using the pre-made one on W3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the `Orders` table to join in `Customers` from the `OrderDetails` since `OrderDetails` doesn't contain the `customerid` that is needed for you to get to that `customers` table.

A better query would be:

```
    SELECT orderDetails.OrderDetailID, customers.CustomerName
    FROM OrderDetails orderDetails
        INNER JOIN Orders orders on orderDetails.OrderID = orders.OrderID
        INNER JOIN Customers customers on orders.customerID = customers.customerID
        INNER JOIN Products products on prderDetails.ProductID = products.ProductID
    WHERE products.SupplierID = 5;
```

Here we avoid `Natural Joins` since those can be unpredictable and when writing SQL it's always a good idea to be as explicit as possible. Furthermore, we use the `Orders` table to get the link to `customers`.

Comment: "Natural Joins... can be unpredictable" -- if you are worried about a situation where they can be 'unpredictable' then you can code defensively (which is good practice anyhow, right?) e.g. use views with privileges.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the comma (which is shorthand for `CROSS JOIN`) with another `NATURAL JOIN`. Also, when using `NATURAL JOIN` you don't need to use range variables i.e. change `OrderDetails.OrderDetailID` to simply `OrderDetailID`:

```
SELECT OrderDetailID, CustomerName
  FROM OrderDetails
       NATURAL JOIN Orders
       NATURAL JOIN Customers
       NATURAL JOIN Products
 WHERE SupplierID = 5;
```

Comment: You may not need the join to Products.